# css style different when appyling to submit than href

Tags: html, css, styles

I'm using the following css to format buttons in a php page:

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1; /* zoom and *display = ie7 hack for display:inline-block*/
    *display: block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    margin: 0 2px;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font: 14px/100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: .5em 2em .55em;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-border-radius: .5em !important;
    -moz-border-radius: .5em !important;
    border-radius: .5em !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2) !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.60);
}
```

If I do apply this class like this:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a class=\"button\" href=\"fr_right.php?op=extendida\">
      << Regresar 
    </a>
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td>
    <input type=submit class=\"button\" value=\"Guardar Cambios\">
  </td>
</tr>
```

I get different button  highs. Other styles are ok (text, color, etc)

As seen, both are within the same table so there shouldn't be any "hidden" code between both.

Regards

Alvaro

Comment: buttons has default styles set by the browser, use a css reset or overwrite them yourself to get a consistent look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it from `<input>` to `<button>` and add `-webkit-appearance: none;` to the start of your `.button` css you can also add `height : 30px` to the css

```
.button{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   height: 30px;
   /* the rest of your css */
   ...
}
```